# How do I get the direct link for a Google Drive video (Google Drive API v3)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'd like to make a function which converts Google Drive videos into VLC streamable links (e.g. `vlc://https://WEBSITE.com/FILE_ID.mkv`.

I've tried methods which were shared on stack overflow, such as modifying the Google Drive link to:
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`

All the methods I've tried seem to not work anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what code you're using? You've tagged this as google-drive-api but it doesn't appear that that's what you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out the answer.

Google Drives' API has a download feature, you just need to make a request to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?alt=media&key=API_KEY`

Now this doesn't generate a direct file path ending with `.mp4` or `.mkv` but VLC and PotPlayer are able to recognize this link like this:

`potplayer://https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?alt=media&key=API_KEY`
`vlc://https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?alt=media&key=API_KEY`

Edit: this doesn't work in development, Google prevents bots from making requests like that. To work around this you need to set a header in your request. e.g.

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?alt=media&key=API_KEY"
r = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken})
```

You get the `accessToken` from the Google Drive API

Answer (score -1):

Just make the file public and copy your ID.
You can find it here: /file/d/**YOUR ID**/view?usp=sharing.
Copy your ID and paste it in this:
drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=**YOUR ID**